# Influxdb database is deleted after query python

Tags: python, influxdb

I am connecting to influxdb through Python and read a database. I only use client.query(query) to get the data from my database. However after I get the data it gets erased from the influxdb. Does anyone have any idea why I lose my data in Influxdb database? The code is given below

```
import time
import datetime
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import numpy as np
start_time = time.time()
host='localhost'
port=8086
user = ''
password = ''
dbname = 'db'


client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)


 query4 = 'select * from rawData ORDER BY time ASC limit 1 ;'
result4 = client.query(query4)
InitialDate = result4.raw['series'][0]['values'][0][0][0:10]
FinalDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(InitialDate, "%Y-%m-       %d")+datetime.timedelta(days=7)
query = 'select count(*) from rawData'
result = client.query(query)
length=result.raw['series'][0]['values'][0][1]
count=0
List = set()
FinalData = {}
while(count*1000000<length):
query2 = 'select * from rawData limit 1000000 '+'offset '+   str(count*1000000)
result2 = client.query(query2)
count=count+1

if ("series" not in result2.raw.keys()):
    continue
temp = result2.raw['series'][0]['values']
print(len(temp))
Data = [temp[i] for i in range(len(temp))
        if (temp[i][4] != '0' and temp[i][0]<=str(FinalDate))]

for i in range(len(Data)):
    List.add(Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4])
for i in range(len(Data)):
    if (Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4]) in FinalData.keys():
        if Data[i][1] in FinalData[Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4]].keys():
            FinalData[Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4]][Data[i]   [1]].append((Data[i][0], Data[i][2]))
        else:
            FinalData[Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4]].update({Data[i][1]: [(Data[i][0], Data[i][2])]})

    else:
        FinalData[Data[i][3] + ' ' + Data[i][4]] = {Data[i][1]: [(Data[i][0], Data[i][2])]}
np.save('my_file2.npy', FinalData)
```

Comment: I don't think your script is deleting anything, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I think so but I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: You should consider cleaning up your example code. Indentation is extremely important to get right in python. It's hard to know what's going on when your code example is guaranteed to fail. Maybe consider using PEP8 as well: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/